# How to generate Rich Text Format (RTF) document in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

How to generate Rich Text Format (RTF) document in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RTF specification from Microsoft:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140277%28office.10%29.aspx

Or, in order to bypass the RTF learning curve, you could generate HTML from ASP.NET then shell out and use the html2rtf tool to convert it to rtf:
http://www.gkrueger.com/personal/html2rtf/index.html

Or, if your doc is going to be used in template-like manner, you could create the rtf file by hand in WordPad and save it with special strings that you invent, like $YOUR_NAME_HERE$.   Later, you read the your saved rtf file and replace your special strings.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the spec:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format

Answer (score 0):

Start your file with

```
MyFile.WriteLine("{\\rtf1 ")
```

and just follow the spec linked by Spencer.